# RTCDataChannel communication between server and client

Tags: web, webrtc

I am going to create real time web application and would like to use WebRTC RTCDataChannel to exchange data between client and server.

WebRTC is created for peer-to-peer communication. However, is it possible to do data exchanging between server and client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! You could use a WebRTC implementation and build your server from the ground up. Will feel like using a HTTP library and setting your own endpoints.

- https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc (Python)
- GStreamer’s webrtcbin (C)
- https://github.com/shinyoshiaki/werift-webrtc (Typescript)
- https://github.com/pion/webrtc (Golang)
- https://github.com/webrtc-rs/webrtc (Rust)
- https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c (C/Embedded)
- https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/ (C++)
- https://github.com/rawrtc/rawrtc (C++)
- https://github.com/sipsorcery-org/sipsorcery (C#)
- https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel (C++)

Or you could run a WebRTC server and write an extension/modify it. This will get you something working quicker.

- https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway
- https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet
- https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup
- https://github.com/pion/ion-sfu
- https://galene.org
- https://github.com/peer-calls/peer-calls

Happy to answer more directed questions. I think it depends on what languages/tools you feel comfortable with.